# Export Named Table from Excel to Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, export

---

OK.  I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time.  Like a DUMMY i didn't think simple solution first. The amount of data i am dealing with isn't too large and will actually work better just exporting to an excel file (i'm pretty sure).  I would like to thank all that helped (June7, Parfait, and HansUp).  The support you guys (everyone on this forum) give has made my job easier by far.

---

I'm trying to export an Excel Table from my active excel file to an Access database file. 
I was getting an error at

"con.excecute sql"

"Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Query input must contain at least one table or query."

```
Sub updateAccess()

Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim connectionString As String

Dim sql, newTable As String
Filename = "C:\Desktop\Quote-Size_Contacts.accdb"
connectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" & Filename

con.Open connectionString

' Save current table ("ContactsTbl_Data") to another table ("ContactsTbl_Data_yyyymmdd_hh_mmss")
newTable = "Quote-Size_Contacts_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & Format(Now, "hhmmss")
sql = "SELECT CODE, STORE INTO " & newTable & "FROM ContactsTbl_Data"
con.Execute sql

' Delete rows of current table ("ContactsTbl_Data")
sql = "DELETE FROM ContactsTbl_Data"
con.Execute sql

' Insert new rows into current table ("ContactsTbl_Data") from my Excel Sheet
sql = "INSERT INTO ContactsTbl_Data ([CODE], [STORE]) " & _
      "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "].[" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Name & "$]"
con.Execute sql

con.Close
Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

EDIT::
I'm not sure standard protocol for these forums on cleaning up the code and asking more questions so i'll just put an "Edit" here.
I applied the suggestions and matched the fields it was trying to save to my access file. I now get the error: "Method 'Execute' of object '_Connection' failed"

```
Public Sub updateAccess()

Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim connectionString As String

Dim sql, newTable As String
Filename = "C:\Desktop\Quote-Size_Contacts.accdb"
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='" & Filename & "'"

con.Open connectionString

' Save current table ("ContactsTbl_Data") to another table ("ContactsTbl_Data_yyyymmdd_hh_mmss")
newTable = "Quote-Size_Contacts_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & Format(Now, "hhmmss")
sql = "SELECT Company, Contact, Initials, Position, Address, AddressContd, CityStatePost, MainNo, CellNo, FaxNo, Email INTO [" & newTable & "] FROM ContactsTbl_Data"
con.Execute sql

' Delete rows of current table ("ContactsTbl_Data")
sql = "DELETE FROM ContactsTbl_Data"
con.Execute sql

' Insert new rows into current table ("ContactsTbl_Data") from my Excel Sheet
sql = "INSERT INTO ContactsTbl_Data ([Company], [Contact], [Initials], [Position], [Address], [AddressContd], [CityStatePost], [MainNo], [CellNo], [FaxNo], [Email]) " & _
      "SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "].[" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Name & "$]"
con.Execute sql

con.Close
Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried another code that actually opens the database file like its going to do something but then i get the error: "Could not find installable ISAM."

Comment: Is your Excel file an `.xls` or `.xlsx` format?

Comment: it is in .xlsm format

Comment: Then use: `[Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=...`

Comment: I tested 8.0 code from an xlsm file and the SQL successfully executed but then my computer crashed.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps.

Table name has hyphen (-) character so use [ ] characters to delimit. Add a space in front of FROM so text doesn't run together in compiled SQL string.

`sql = "SELECT CODE, STORE INTO [" & newTable & "] FROM ContactsTbl_Data"`

As for connection to Access database, don't think I've ever used or seen Driver, I use Provider:
`connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='" & Filename & "'"`

Comment: con.execute sql is still highlighted but i get a new error:  "[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters"

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Are you sure you have a space before the `FROM` clause like this answer shows but not your original answer. Otherwise, query suggests there may not be a `CODE` or `STORE` column in `ContactsTbl_Data` table.